# jQuery.support Performance Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am trying to speed up the loading time of a large web page. Using Firefox's profiler, I found that most of the loading time is spent in the function that generates the `jQuery.support` object. Is there any reason that this function takes a long time on a large web page? And if so, how could I increase the performance?

Comment: `jQuery.support` isn't a function, it's an object.

Comment: @Barmar You're correct, I should have looked at its definition more closely. It defines a function and immediately calls it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Modernizr insted of using the jQuery.support feature.

Modernizr is a framework that only focuses on telling you what is supported by the browser and what is not.

http://modernizr.com/

For the performance hit I don't know why it performs poorly on a large site.

EDIT:
The jQuery people even states on their site that you should use Modernizr instead of jQuery.support:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.support/

Comment: Using Modernizr sped it up significantly. Thanks!